# Неправильно выделяется память в динамическом массиве в классе

Tags: c++

При пошаговом дибаге выдает ошибку в конструкторах
CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated

В чем тут ошибка?

```
class Str
{
public:
    Str();
    Str(int n);
    Str(char str[]);
    ~Str();
    void output();

private:
    char* _str;
    int _n;
};

Str::Str()
{
    _n = 0;
    _str = new char[_n];
}
Str::Str(int n)
{
    _n = n;
    _str = new char[_n];    
}

Str::Str(char str[])
{
    int _n  = strlen(str);
    _str = new char[_n];    
    //strcpy(_str, str);
    for (int i = 0; i < _n; i ++)
    {
        _str[i] = str[i];
    }
}

void Str::output()
{
    std::cout << _str << std::endl;
}
Str::~Str()
{
    delete[] _str;
}
int main()
{
    Str e;
    e.output();
    Str a;
    Str b(1);
    Str c("123");
    b.output();
    c.output();
}
```

[image: Окно вывода]

Comment: в строках нет терминируещего нуля... от этого много проблем... в купе с другими ошибками...

Answer (score 0):

```
Str::Str(const char * str)
{
    _n  = strlen(str)  + 1;
```

Нужна не **локальная** `_n`, а член класса.

И еще - нужно на 1 символ больше (завершающий нулевой)!

Еще - не все компиляторы умеют выделять нуль байт:

```
_n = 0;
_str = new char[_n];
```

И, кстати, начинать имена с подчерков - плохая практика. Реально плохая...

Вот ваш, немного исправленный, код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


class Str
{
public:
    Str(size_t n = 1);
    Str(const char *str);
    ~Str();
    void output();

private:
    char* _str;
    size_t _n;
};

Str::Str(size_t n)
{
    _n = n;
    *(_str = new char[_n]) = 0;
}

Str::Str(const char *str)
{
    _n  = strlen(str)+1;
    _str = new char[_n];    
    strcpy(_str, str);
}

void Str::output()
{
    std::cout << _str << std::endl;
}

Str::~Str()
{
    delete[] _str;
}

int main()
{
    Str e;
    e.output();
    Str a;
    Str b(1);
    Str c("123");
    b.output();
    c.output();
}
```

Comment: На что это повлияет в коде вопроса?

Comment: @Fat-Zer У меня - да, а у Дарьи - `int n_ = ...`

Comment: @Igor На работоспособность :)

Comment: @Harry ни на что

Comment: @Igor Да без проблем. Если вы не планируете смотреть вперед хотя бы на шаг...

Comment: @Harry Это ответ не на тот вопрос - был.

Answer (score 0):

```
Str::Str()
{
    _n = 0;
    _str = NULL;
}

Str::Str(int n)
{
    _n = n;
    _str = new char[_n + 1];
    _str[0] = '\0';
}

Str::Str(char str[])
{
    _n  = strlen(str);
    _str = new char[_n + 1];    
    ...
    _str[_n] = '\0';
}
```